# SQL - Compare datetime with current datetime

Tags: sql, datetime

I am building a banner rotation system, and in my sql table i have a datetime field to store when the banner will join the print queue, and a field to store when it leaves. I need a query to show all of them that are in the queue when I load the page.

I tried this with no success:

```
SELECT * 
FROM banners 
WHERE banner_start_date <= NOW() 
    AND banner_end_date >= NOW()
```

I'm using this with PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please define "no success?" is it that it returns *nothing* or does it not return expected results? what are you expecting? which rdbms are you using? thanks!

Comment: check the client and DB server dates, maybe they are not the same and it is returning results not as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * FROM banners 
WHERE now() between banner_start_date AND banner_end_date
```

Comment: This is a easier way to do it, but it's basically the same condition that op already has. How is this supposed to retrieve different results that the query he's using?

Comment: Additionally, `BETWEEN` may be less clean [according to some](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: @swasheck: I beg to differ. `BETWEEN` is a lot cleaner. And the criticism in that blog post is more about implicit data type casting (for date literals) than anything else (additionally not every DBMS behaves SQL Server when it comes to dates and date literals)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name fair enough. i agree with your point, in principle, but knowing when/where type casting would require thoughtful implementation. i guess my comment is probably throwing the baby out with the bathwater